# How to change String that contains month and year only using simpledateformat

Tags: android

im having trouble with SimpleDateFormat. as I'm new to Android Studio Java
I have this string
which is String monthYear = "05/2019".

I want to change it to String monthYear = "May 2019".

may i know how to achieve this by having the result back as string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```java
// from string to date
String monthYear = "05/2019";  
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");  
Date date = inputFormat.parse(monthYear);  

// from date to string
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");   
String dateTime = outputFormat.format(date);
```